# Set default value for interact in jupyter notebooks

Tags: python-3.x, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have a problem with a widget. It is a selection list that selects the range of months for a graph output. This means the value which is used to fill the following line.
`df4[(df4.year_month >= begin) &(df4.year_month <= end)]`
After the dataframe is filtered, a graph appears. The problem is that the widget is set to `min(df)` for both the beginning and the end of the graph. Therefore I would like to set a default value. Unfortunately, I don't know how.

All works fine with

`interact(f,begin=list(df4.year_month),end=list(df4.year_month))`

from other widgets i know that it is possible to set

```
`end = widgets.Dropdown(
    options=list(df.year_month),
    value=max(list(df.year_month)),
    description='End:',
    disabled=False,`
```

Is it possible to link the two variants withindner or add the term `value=max (list (df. year_month))` to the first one?

So this is what i get:

[Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWxBJ.png)

And this is what i want:

[Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPfIP.png)

Thank you very much for your efforts!

Answer (score 0):

I ve build a workaround. i saved `list (df. year_month)` to `listTimestamp` and set `end=sorted(listTimestamp, reverse=True)`